# Static ip on lan devices with unmanaged or smart switch?

Tags: networking, home-networking

I am building a pfsense box with only 2 ethernet ports. If I get an unmanaged switch (or smart switch?) will I be able to give certain mac address static ip on my lan? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, since a switch has nothing to do with setting (or handing out) IP addresses.

The IP address is either:

- configured on the PCs themselves (static IP)
- or they ask for a IP from a DHCP server.

A regular unmanaged switch does nothing special in either case. The PC/laptops/whatever/... either have their static IPs, or they send a broadcast DHCP request. If there is a DHCP server then that program might respond to that DHCP request, and it can do so based on the MAC address of the requester.  (The switch does not change the MAC address, it merely forwards local traffic).

Now if you get a managed switch then the answer becomes much more interesting and mostly based on that switch's capabilities.

(Are there any managed/smart switches with build in DHCP servers?)

Comment: I see; so because the router will have a DHCP server on it, it will be the router that does the ip assigning. Is it possible to create a VLAN with unmanaged switch? I want to isolate my desktop traffic from other devices on my LAN.

Comment: On the switch itself? No. There is no interface to create a VLAN.  Creating it on a NIC itself and then passing VLAN traffic though an unmanaged switch however can work, though it depends on the hardware. Some [cheap] switches might drop the last four bytes of the frames or have similar problems.

Comment: The behavior of unmanaged switches with VLAN-tagged packets is unpredictable. If you want/need VLANs, get a managed switch that supports VLANs and you won't have to wonder if it will work. Some can be quite affordable.